# How to merge a branch the second time without modifiying its content in Git?

Tags: git, merge

I am learning Git, and in the merge part, I've come out this question..
I am in master demo.txt, I use git merge test, then the new content in demo.txt of the test branch has been added to my master demo.txt.
Then I remove the new content and use the merge command again, the git says content is 'Already up to date'. And I am no able to merge those content again into my master branch.
What command I can use to merge test branch into my master branch again without modifying the test branch?

I know if I modified test branch and commit, I will be able to merge it into master branch again.
I am assuming that the branch in Git is like a variable, and its content can be used for several times, so I delete new content in master branch, I can get it back by using git merge test again.

Answer (score 2):

> I am assuming that the branch in Git is like a variable, and its content can be used for several times, so I delete new content in master branch, I can get it back by using git merge test again.

This is mostly wrong.

When you are merging a branch `A` into another `main`, you're actually merging commits of `A` since the last common ancestor of both branches into `main`.

After you've merged once, the new common ancestor of both branches is actually the merge commit just created.

Trying to merge again will have no effect because there's no commit in `A` that you don't already have in `main`.

Note that, even if you commit to `A` again, merging again will only bring in `master` the latest `A` commit, not all the previous ones.

---

Now, for your use case, it depends what state you're actually trying to achieve.

You could:

- **revert** the `main` commit that removed the changes you want to get back again
- **cherry-pick** a specific commit of `test` to apply it again on `main`
- **reset** `main` to a previous state

Comment: The general idea is correct. I have to add a correction: the common ancestor of both branches after merge is not the merge commit itself. It's the tip of the _other_ branch you are merging.

Comment: Yes, kinda of explain the reason..